# Bike sizing question - are these two sizes actually that different?

Tags: commuter, bike-fit, commuting-bike

Could use some advice on bike sizing. I'm in the market for a new commuter and after a lot of research I ended up picking this one:
https://www.bergamont.com/gb/en/product/bergamont-vitess-n8-belt-gent#geometry

Unfortunately it's online only so couldn't try it and returns cost £35. I'm 6'0" (183cm) with 33" inseam (84cm). I ordered the large (56) frame but when I hopped on, the top bar was too high and couldn't rest comfortably when standing over it without strong pressure down there.

I'm thinking of ordering the smaller one (52) but **wanted to check with you if it's not too small** (and avoid another £35 return). Comparing the two sizes - there doesn't seem to be much difference apart from the shorter stack/standover! The seat and head tube are slightly shorter (shorter stack) but the reach is the same. **Does that mean that the smaller bike will fit just as well or am I missing something?**

Here's a comparison of the two frame sizes (you can see the comparison if you click 'Shadow bike'):
https://www.bikegeocalc.com/#9Bergamonta0b4c789.58314d280e624.25905f788.81524g993.29239h427.82039i340j340k1446.65227l926m1194.58314n765.75095o1251.33031p1005.28465q1272.29156r1404.18714s1006.29693t31.8u40v6w7.75408x10y280z40A0B150C25D458.77624E42F172.5G30H30Z6Berg+Ma0b4c791.02661d280e642.17724f752.08989g995.28771h435.49726i340j340k1443.36749l907m1198.02661n765.60378o1248.09764p986.28465q1275.73503r1391.63503s986.28465t31.8u40v6w7.75408x10y280z40A0B150C25D458.62011E42F172.5G30H30Z

Also full geometry is on the bike website: https://www.bergamont.com/gb/en/product/bergamont-vitess-n8-belt-gent#geometry

Thanks!

Comment: I share your apparent skepticism over those measurements.  That geometry link shows that the "52" actually has a longer reach than the "56".  That's a bit strange. I think you probably should contact the seller and/or manufacturer directly.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get 40mm more stand-over clearance with the 52 over the 56.

As the reach is about the same on both sizes you will not be cramped by the frame, *but* I suspect the 52 may come with a shorter stem. You may need to buy a longer stem with a little more rise to get the effective (to the handlebar) stack and reach that you need.